# Can I use a digital ring flash with a Nikon film camera?

Tags: flash, film, 35mm, ring-flash

I have two Nikon film cameras (one is an FE2).

Is it possible to fire a modern ring flash made for a DLSR with such equipment, or do I need a dedicated unit?

I have hot shoe adapters and sync cables, so I have some flexibility with connectivity, but I am guessing they need to be Nikon-compatible.

If this is possible, does anyone have any product advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sync cable is a sync cable. If your camera has a PC port that your cable fits and your flash has a PC port that your cable fits then the camera should be able to fire the flash. Of course you will need to control the flash power manually when using a PC connection. If the flash in question doesn't allow for that it probably doesn't have a generic PC port.

*PC in the context of flash photography has nothing to do with a personal computer. It is an abbreviation of *Prontor/Compur*. Prontor has its origins in the Italian word *pronto* (quick) and was a brand of shutter produced by Alfred Gauthier in the 1950s. *Compur*, derived from the word *compound*, was the shutter brand of the Deckel Company. Both companies were based in Germany and both counted Zeiss as an influential stockholder when they introduced the standard 1/8"-inch coaxial connector for shutter/flash synchronization.

Comment: Very comprehensive!

Comment: However it's worth mentioning that many modern ringflashes don't have a lot if manual controls on them so although a sync cable (or basic X-sync hotshoe adaptor) will trigger the flash, you may not have much/any control over the light output and will need to instead vary your aperture and/or ISO setting to control exposure.

Comment: Would such a flash without manual controls be likely to have a generic PC port?

Comment: I have a decent light meter, and I tend to push and pull with the flash (ie deliberately over expose).