# What does the "P" and "C" in "PC sync terminal" stand for?

Tags: flash, terminology

I don't know the underlying science to which I refer when I talk about a PC sync terminal connection between camera & electronic flash.  What's the meaning of the letters "P" & "C"  in PC sync terminal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Sync Terminal Adapter?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/42438/what-is-a-sync-terminal-adapter)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use remote flash trigger for remote shutter release](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/45392/use-remote-flash-trigger-for-remote-shutter-release)

Answer (score 17):

It stands for "[Prontor-Compur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prontor-Compur#Etymology) connection":

> "Prontor" has its origins in the Italian word "pronto", meaning ready (and was a leaf shutter made by Alfred Gauthier). "Compur" is derived from the word "compound" (the "Compound" was a long-lived series of leaf shutters made by Friedrich Deckel).

Comment: Hat’s off – that’s enlightening – I always thought the PC was short for “pin connector”. My cameras take a 3.5mm PC

Comment: related: http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/73041/15871